# Does Binance Api support Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, binance

I'm trying to developing a mobile application in kotlin about binance.
I have problem with Binance api issues.Does Binance Api support Kotlin aswell like Java?

I mean I want to develop that project on binance and when I asked to chatGPT for help.It gives me an implementation and some codes. Implementation is `implementation 'com.binance.api:binance-java-api:1.1.10'` and the code is:

```
import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiClientFactory

import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiRestClient

val apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
val secretKey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"

val factory = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance(apiKey, secretKey)
val client = factory.newRestClient()
```

I was just trying to do a simple connection for binance with api key and secret key in my app.But with that implemantation I mention above I can't import this two libraries

```
import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiClientFactory

import com.binance.api.client.BinanceApiRestClient
```

That's why the rest of the code also gives an error.

What I tried:

- I tried to adding maven as dependencies to build.gradle but it didn't effect (I don't know if I should add.It is one of ChatGPT's
  advice)
- I also tried to this two libraries as external.I mean I found that two import library in this github repo
  https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api
  .It's for Java but I guess Kotlin supports Java Libraries too.That's why I
  added this two import libraries to libs directory like below.But
  imports still didn't effected. [image]
- Lastly I tried retrofit for that. I also heard some developers did it with that way.

interface BinanceService

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface BinanceService {
    @GET("api/v3/account")
    fun getAccountInfo(
        @Query("apiKey") apiKey: String,
        @Query("secretKey") secretKey: String
    ): Call<AccountInfoResponse>
}
```

AccountInfoResponse data class

```
data class AccountInfoResponse(
    @SerializedName("balances")
    val balances: List<AssetBalance>,
)

data class AssetBalance(
    @SerializedName("asset")
    val asset: String,
    @SerializedName("free")
    val free: String,
    @SerializedName("locked")
    val locked: String
)
```

Usage in code is like this also

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

val apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
val secretKey = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.binance.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

val binanceService = retrofit.create(BinanceService::class.java)
val call = binanceService.getAccountInfo(apiKey, secretKey)

call.enqueue(object : Callback<AccountInfoResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<AccountInfoResponse>, response: Response<AccountInfoResponse>) {
        val accountInfo = response.body()
       
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<AccountInfoResponse>, t: Throwable) {
       
    }
})
```

Here is my build.gradle (app) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.binancetradebot'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.binancetradebot"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}



def lottieVersion = "3.7.0"
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"
    implementation 'com.binance.api:binance-java-api:1.1.10'
    implementation files('libs/binance-api-1.0.9.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

But with that code the response always returns null even my connection and keys are true.

So I have questions

1. Can I do that this app with kotlin?
2. If I can do which path I should try? (implementation way, adding Java library or retrofit usage)
3. And if I select one of them what is my wrong about it?

Comment: Anything written in Java can be used in Kotlin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah i know right but i couldn't find anything for Kotlin so far.

Comment: Anything you can do in Java, you can do in Kotlin, just with different syntax. If you want to learn how to do this, I recommend using tutorials written by humans, preferably from official sources. ChatGPT is literally asking “someone” who has read a bunch of stuff but has never actually written their own code, so might be wrong about details or not really understand what you’re asking or the answer it’s giving you. It might be a useful tool when you know enough to be able to tell when it’s wrong, but from what I’ve seen is nothing but trouble for newbies.

Comment: I haven’t used Binance, or I could help more. It does appear like you don’t have your Gradle dependencies configured correctly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah I found some community projects but I couldn't understand them exactly.

Comment: you can't just add `.java` files to the `libs` folder, because it's typically expecting `.jar` files instead. As Tenfour04 said, there's probably a problem with your gradle configuration/build file

Comment: @user2340612 yeah the implementation isn't correct if you want to take look at build.graddle (app) I can share it on here.For these external libraries I added implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.java']) instead of jar but didn't work.

Comment: probably a stupid question, but have you reloaded the gradle project in Android Studio? Otherwise it won't download the dependencies

Comment: @user2340612 if you mean sync the gradle yeah i did it.

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if you could share your Gradle build file

Comment: @user2340612 okey I added it.And also tried to add jar file as import but it didn't effect again.

Comment: I did a quick search in Maven Central and Google's Maven repo and there is no artifact named `com.binance.api:binance-java-api`. Looking at the README of the binance-java-api GitHub repo you shared, it says you have to build it and install it into your Maven local repository – see [here](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/tree/master#installation). That's why it's failing.. in your build logs you should see that it fails to download that dependency, because it doesn't exist

Comment: @user2340612 oh okey.I didn't know that. In that github repo it says two step for installation but I didn't understand that steps exactly.I mean what is Maven's local repository?I didn't see any maven in my project.

Comment: it's just a (hidden) folder on your computer, typically under `C:\Users\<your_user>\.m2` if you're on Windows. It gets created by Maven automatically when you do `mvn install` if it doesn't exist

Comment: @user2340612 okey thanks for information. I will try that with chat gpt helps and other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if the `binance-java-api` is not in the Maven Central or any other repository that you are currently using, you won't be able to import it. Is seems like a chatGPT hallucination.

If you want to use https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api you could do a couple of things:

- Install a local Maven repository and modify the build.gradle to use the locally installed maven repository. There is a good stack here on how to do that: [How to add a Maven project as a Gradle dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057574/how-to-add-a-maven-project-as-a-gradle-dependency)

Or

- You could `package` the `binance-java-api` as a .jar file and copy it to the libs directory in your app and include it in your build.gradle.  There are a lot of resources on how to do that.

  ```
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
  ```

Or simply go to `File` > `Project Structure` > `Dependencies` and import the .jar from there.

Here is the dialog:
[Add local dependencies in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6ZuW.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for help 
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
fixed my problem otherwise I couldn't import the binance library.In the stackoverflow link that you sent is including that code fixed.You can add this code to  your solution.It is really important.